# Visually line up animation with distance traveled?

Tags: java, animation

I'm programming a simple 2D Java game, and I've got an animation of a guy going from a standing start, to running as the user moves him.  The animation resets back to standing when the user releases the arrow keys.

The problem is when the guy starts running and the first few frames play, before he's moved very far his back leg is already way behind where he was initially standing.  It gives him the appearance that he's "slipping" as he takes the step. I mean instead of his body moving forward as if the step is planted on the ground, the next frame shows his foot way behind him and he hasn't moved an equivalent amount.

I'm not sure of the solution because I'm new to this but I've got 3 possibilities.

A) Play with the timing of how long each frame is displayed and/or his velocity (which as of now is constant, maybe it should be variable somehow)?

B) Add in more frames in between my 5 or 6 frames I currently have?  This way he'll have moved further by the time his leg is all the way back?

C) Add some kind of offset to each of the frames to fake his leg being planted on the ground (my worry here is that the animation wouldn't look as smooth)

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have covered all the options in your question.

If you can't alter the velocity to your satisfaction, either you will have to alter your frames in the animation such that each one 'moves' the character an equal number of pixels (and then experiment with the velocity), or you will have to have an array of values per animation, one value per frame in the animation. The you would use these to alter the x-value as the animation is progressed.

Comment: Ok, looking again at my frames, there is a rather large gap between the first two.  I think adding another frame or two between them should be the first thing I try.  Next would be playing with the velocity.  I can't upvote yet, but thanks for the help.